# Prevent a user from "hammering" a web service

Tags: web-services, security, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a MVC 5 internet application with a web service that is hosted on Azure. I am wanting to implement some sort of security that prevents any users from "hammering" the web service. When I say "hammering", I am referring to a user constantly attacking a url thousands of times.

I have done some research online, yet cannot find any relevant resources.

Should I write my own code for this, or is there a library/tool that I can implement?

I am thinking of doing the following if I should write this myself:

1. Each time a user accesses the web service, increment a count variable for the ip address.
2. If the ip address count variable exceeds a number (i.e. 1000), do not send the web service data to the user

Before I write this myself, is there a library/tool that I can implement instead of writing my own?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to add that I am not using a virtual machine, and instead, I have a website with a web API service.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It appears you're basicly coming here asking us how to solve your problem without doing any work yourself. Please read up on how to ask good questions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I am basically asking the community if there is a security tool that could help, or if I should write my own...

Comment: What about people who work behind a NAT'd gateway where all their IP addresses will be the same? There could be hundreds of concurrent connections all with the same IP. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Note that you could use the rate limiting policy features of API Management (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/) to help out here.

Comment: One term you might be looking for (to assist in your research) is "throttling."

Comment: By the time you see the request its already at your web server. If someone hits the server and you should fully and correctly process the request. In Dos attacks with 1000's of requests then dealing with it in code is too late and the only real resolution is using hosting infrastructure that deals with it. If its a free services then you really need to make it scale as required (See @Simon W). If its a paid service with identified users then you could count the user accesses and send them an email about their 'activity' patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure provides protection already for DDoS attacks. Take a look at the [Microsoft Azure Trust Center](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/) documentation.  There is a ton of protection and detection built into the platform and as for best practices for writing secure code, you will find that in the resources section of the trust center.  But, writing code to count the number of requests from an IP address as you mentioned is not the way to go.  Simon W points out an obvious problem with this approach in the comments.

Comment: As an Azure customer, am I correct in saying that I do not personally need to worry about DDoS attacks as Azure has a team that will monitor these threats?

Comment: Taken from the trust center documentation: Intrusion detection and DDoS. Intrusion detection and prevention systems, denial of service attack prevention, regular penetration testing, and forensic tools help identify and mitigate threats from both outside and inside of Azure.

Comment: Also, look at the resources in the trust center to learn more about the red team and blue team at MSFT.  If you want to see a quick video on it, check out http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Red-vs-Blue-Internal-security-penetration-testing-of-Microsoft-Azure

Comment: This is *not* suggesting that you are guaranteed to never suffer from an attack.  But, there are resources far more sophisticated at work to help identify and mitigate it than your suggested "counting code" would achieve.  This empowers you to focus on what's strategic to your application and less on the infrastructure it's running on.

Comment: But do I need to implement the Intrusion detection and DDoS when having an Azure website, or is it part of the service by default? I have read the resource, but am still a little confused.